# Mínimo valor visible en chartjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

Estoy haciendo una gráfica con chartjs :http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

El problema que tengo es que, en este caso tengo 3 columnas, y el valor de la menor es un 2 entonces la gráfica empieza en 2 en vez de en 0, por lo tanto una de las columnas no es visible... :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ctx = document.getElementById("reporte_tecnicos").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
    labels: [<?php while($count<$i){echo $data_n[$count]; $count++;} ?>],
    datasets: [{
        label: '',
        backgroundColor: [
            "rgba(0, 150, 254, 0.5)",
            "rgba(150, 100, 50, 0.5)",
            "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5)",
            "rgba(255, 100, 0, 0.5)",
            "rgba(150, 100, 50, 0.5)",
            "rgba(100, 254, 0.5)",
            "rgba(25, 100, 200, 0.5)",
            "rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.5)",
            "rgba(80, 20, 0, 0.5)",
            "rgba(255, 50, 254, 0.5)"
        ],
        data: [<?php while($count2<$i){echo $data_r[$count2]; $count2++;} ?>],
        options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                beginAtZero: true
            }]
            }
        }
        }],
    }
    });
</script>
```

He visto en la documentación hay una opción que es beginAtZero pero no me funciona ni al ponerlo en yAxes ni en xAxes

Cómo puedo evitar esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chart.js te permite personalizar las gráficas pasando un objeto a la entrada `options` de la configuración de la gráfica. Este objeto puede almacenar muchas configuraciones, como para fuentes, tooltips, y ejes.

En tu caso, la configuración que debes personalizar es para el eje `Y` (`yAxis`), pasando un `tick` con la personalización de dicho eje.

> He visto en la documentación hay una opción que es beginAtZero pero no me funciona ni al ponerlo en yAxes ni en xAxes

Eso es porque `beginAtZero` debe estar dentro de `ticks`:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("reporte_tecnicos").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: [<?php while($count<$i){echo $data_n[$count]; $count++;} ?>],
    datasets: [{
      label: '',
      backgroundColor: [
        "rgba(0, 150, 254, 0.5)",
        "rgba(150, 100, 50, 0.5)",
        "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5)",
        "rgba(255, 100, 0, 0.5)",
        "rgba(150, 100, 50, 0.5)",
        "rgba(100, 254, 0.5)",
        "rgba(25, 100, 200, 0.5)",
        "rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.5)",
        "rgba(80, 20, 0, 0.5)",
        "rgba(255, 50, 254, 0.5)"
      ],
      data: [<?php while($count2<$i){echo $data_r[$count2]; $count2++;} ?>],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

---

**Nota:** código válido para Chart.js 2.0 o superior. Para versión 1.x usar `scaleOverride` y `scaleStartValue` como lo indica la respuesta de @lois6b.

Comment: buena puntualizacion la de las versiones ^^

Comment: Así es mi querido amigo ;)

Comment: Tengo la versión 2.5 y aún copiando tal cual tu código no me ha funcionado. Sigue empezando en 2 en vez de 0... Y la consola no da ningún error.

Comment: @PavloB. cometí un pequeño error de typo. El objeto `options` **no debe ir dentro de datasets**, si no fuera. Mira [éste ejemplo que hice en JSFiddle](http://bit.ly/2kNs5df) para que veas un ejemplo en vivo. He editado mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Como dicen en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28991320/3045491) tienes que sobreescribir `scales`:

Añadiendo:

```
scaleOverride : true,
scaleStartValue : 0,
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ctx = document.getElementById("reporte_tecnicos").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
scaleOverride : true,
scaleStartValue : 0,
data: {
labels: [<?php while($count<$i){echo $data_n[$count]; $count++;} ?>],
datasets: [{
    label: '',
    backgroundColor: [
        "rgba(0, 150, 254, 0.5)",
        "rgba(150, 100, 50, 0.5)",
        "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5)",
        "rgba(255, 100, 0, 0.5)",
        "rgba(150, 100, 50, 0.5)",
        "rgba(100, 254, 0.5)",
        "rgba(25, 100, 200, 0.5)",
        "rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.5)",
        "rgba(80, 20, 0, 0.5)",
        "rgba(255, 50, 254, 0.5)"
    ],
    data: [<?php while($count2<$i){echo $data_r[$count2]; $count2++;} ?>],
    options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            beginAtZero: true
        }]
        }
    }
    }],
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, dónde quedaría eso dentro de mi código?

Comment: @PavloB. mira el edit